# How to write a query to get specific day records between given date range?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with start date and end date columns. I have a use case in which user will be having a drop down with options [**Monday to Sunday and Daily**]. So whenever a user clicks a specific day then the query should return all the records on that specific day between start date and end date.

**Example:** If the user selects Monday in the drop down then I need all the records from Monday in the table in that specific date range based on start date and end date columns.

**Sample Inputs**
Start Date: 2021-06-20
End Date: 2021-06-30
Option: Moday

**Courses table**
| Start Date    | End Date      |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
| 2021-06-21    | 2021-06-21    |
| 2021-06-22    | 2021-06-22    |
| 2021-06-23    | 2021-06-23    |

If sample input is applied on the above table then the result should be as follows.

**Expected Result**
| Start Date    | End Date      |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
| 2021-06-21    | 2021-06-21    |
**Query:** The below query will retrieve all the records between specified date ranges. In the below given date range there is one monday so the expected output would be recorded on **2021-06-21** as it is the only monday in the given date range..

```sql
SELECT * FROM courses 
WHERE ((start_date BETWEEN '2021-06-20' AND '2021-06-30') 
OR (end_date BETWEEN '2021-06-20' AND '2021-06-30'));
```

**Current Result:**
| Start Date    | End Date      |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
| 2021-06-21    | 2021-06-21    |
| 2021-06-22    | 2021-06-22    |
| 2021-06-23    | 2021-06-23    |

Current result is based on the above SQL query.

Comment: Hi there! Please, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
In order to help you, I would need to know your DBMS, some dummy data and the exoected output of the desired query.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  You have described two *intervals*.  But a time interval doesn't have a day-of-the-week.  That makes your intentions rather confusing.  What is the "specific day"?  In addition, your range has **two** Mondays.

Comment: Sorry, @SaiHemanthTalasila. I am still unable to understand the underlying problem you are trying to solve. Where do `courses` dates come from?